# One object, multiple onclick events

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps

I am fairly new to javascript and I have been stuck with this problem for the last couple of hours.

I have one map object and I attach one event to it, so if the user clicks on the map I want to get the coordinats of the mouse button. I then want the user to click on another point on the map to get a second pair of coordinates, I then want to draw a line between these two points. So far I am able to do this by having the mouseclick for the first pair of coordinates and getting the second pair of coordinates by listening for the user pressing a button. However I would like to use two mouse clicks. One click in location 1 to get coordinates 1 and one click in location 2 to get the coordinates 2. Everytime I have two onclick events however both of them are fired right away, and I just get a point on the map. I am using Bing map api.

here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?

v=6.2"></script>
  <div><script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null;
    var pinid = 1;
var pixel = null;
var location = null;
var location2 = null;
var pixel2 = null;
var point1 = null;
var point2 = null;
var count = 0;


  function doSomething(e) {
if (!e) var e = window.event; 
e.cancelBubble = true;
if(e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
PixelClick1();
  }

  function GetMap()
  {

     map = new VEMap('myMap');
     map.LoadMap();
     map.SetZoomLevel(10);
 map.AttachEvent("onclick", PixelClick1);


//onclick="doSomething();PixelClick1; return false"
  }

  function onClick(){
count++;
  }



  function AddPolyline()
  {
    var shape = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Polyline, [location2,
                                               location
                                              ]);
map.AddShape(shape);
shape.HideIcon();
point1 = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Polyline,[location,location]);
point2 = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Polyline, [location2, location2]);

      point1.SetTitle('Point1 Location:');
      point2.SetTitle('Point2 Location:');
     point1.SetDescription('(Latitude: ' + location.Latitude + ', 

Longitude: ' + location.Longitude + ')');
point2.SetDescription('(Latitude: ' + location2.Latitude + ', 

 Longitude: ' + location2.Longitude + ')');


point1.HideIcon();  
point2.HideIcon();
map.AddShape(point1);
map.AddShape(point2);


  }

  function PixelClick1(e){
e.cancelBubble = true;
var x = e.mapX;
var y = e.mapY;
pixel = new VEPixel(x,y);
location = map.PixelToLatLong(pixel);
wait(e);    
return false;
  }



  function  PixelClick2(e){
var x = e.mapX;
var y = e.mapY;
pixel2 = new VEPixel(x,y);
location2 = map.PixelToLatLong(pixel2);
AddPolyline();


  }

  function ShowPushPin(){
point1.ShowIcon();
point2.ShowIcon();
  }

  function HidePushPin(){
point1.HideIcon();
point2.HideIcon();
  }      

  function wait(){

    map.AttachEvent("onkeydown",PixelClick2);

  }

  </script></div>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
      <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:400px; 

 height:400px;"></div>
<div><a href='#' onclick='ShowPushPin();'>Show Pushpins</a></div>
<div><a href='#' onclick='HidePushPin();'>Hide Pushpins</a></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your code (the relevant bits). Maybe you also set up a working sample over at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some kind of flag. 
So while handling the first click event, you set the flag to say 'true' and call a method accordingly 
and then while handling the click event when the flag is already 'false' i.e. you detect a second click; so call another method accordingly.

You don't need to have multiple clickEventListener for this purpose.

Best Regards,

Ravish.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how many click events you put on the same object, they'll always fire at once. What you'll need to do is store your state in a variable, so that it's available the next time your click event is called.

A simplified example (using jQuery):

```
var firstPoint = null;
$('#something').mousedown(function(e) {
    if (!firstPoint) {
        firstPoint = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY};
    } else {
        alert('Line from ' + firstPoint.x + ', ' + firstPoint.y + ' to ' + e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY);
    }
);
```

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag anywhere. Listening for a click event would be more appropriate, and *firstPoint* should be cleared on the second click. :-)

Comment: @RobG it's an simple example to illustrate my point - not a full solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
<!--Put this in your <head> tag-->
var stateOfClick = null;

function initiateLine(){
    document.getElementById('test').value = "Started";
}

function endLine(){
    document.getElementById('test').value = "Line Ended";
}

function createLines(){
  if(!stateOfClick) {
    initiateLine();
    stateOfClick = 1;
  } else {
    endLine();
  }
}
```

then on the object add:-

```
onclick="createLines()"
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/WpLG3/1/